# For disks/RAM, what is the relationship between access time and read/write speed?

Tags: performance, memory, io, performance-testing, ram

I'm trying to better understand how relatively fast HDD/SSD/RAM is when it comes to reading/writing bytes.

Here are the access times and read/write speeds I've found from online sources:

```
Storage | Read/Write speed | Access time
RAM     | 100 GB/s         |   50 ns
SSD     | 0.5 GB/s         |  500 ns
HDD     | 0.1 GB/s         | 5000 ns
```

My initial thought was that access time is the time it takes to read 1 byte, but it looks like these numbers don't support that. What exactly is the difference between read/write speed and access time? How are they related?

Is it safe to say that RAM is `~1,000x` faster than SSD, and SSD is `~100x` faster than HDD, and hence RAM is `~100,000x` faster than HDD?

Comment: Access time is, more or less, the time it takes to read one byte. But reading two bytes doesn't take twice as long as reading one byte.

Comment: Access time is the overhead that's added from reading at a random location.  Moving that disk reader head takes a while.  You can hear it.  Disks are only fast when you don't move the head.  Use superuser.com for questions like this.

Answer (score 3):

Access time or latency means how long the system wait from request until data starts to arrive. Read and write speed are the amount of data transferred per time unit. Usually read and write speeds are different for the same device.

These benchmarks are directly related to the technology adopted by each one. On physical disks (HDD), the read/write speed are directly affected by the rotational speed and the access time are related to the movement of the head.

On SSD storage, speed and access time are related to chip internals and organization. SSD uses multiple flash memory chips which have a natural specific access time and speed to store data. Access time is also affected by the controller that split data through these chips.

RAM modules use dynamic chips (DRAM) that are very fast in speed and access time. The speed is affected by the chip but also affected by the pcb design and data bus of the module. The access time, in some way. is limited by the refresh rate of the chip.

There is also another kind of memory called static RAM (SRAM). SRAM uses a much more expensive technology than DRAM that limits its capacity but far faster than DRAM. It is used on processors cache.

Comparing these technologies, it is safe to say that RAM is much faster than SSD and that SSD is much faster than HDD in general way. Put in number is not so easy because technology evolves and each generation of products have improvements in its performance. Also server application devices have much better performance than consumer products device.

Answer (score 2):

Those seem like slightly inflated estimates but they are in the ball-park. Read and write speeds using a common filesystem are going to be much slower than that. If you are interested in easy to use benchmark utilities, download an ISO for memtest86 and that will tell you the actual RAM throughput for raw data. ArgusMonitor is for windows is demo software but will give you your hard drive speeds with raw data.

Average I've seen is roughly around 20GB/s if I am not mistaken for 800MHz DDR2 RAM using raw data and around 90-130MB/s raw data on a SATA3 HDD. I have not had the finances to bench test a Solid State drive yet, but I have seen that they claim an average about two or three times faster than the SATA3 HDD I have.

Access time are like seek times it seems. A Platter based HDD has to make rotations and the heads have to move into the position of the data be sought (seek) and that takes maybe 1-8 milliseconds which is sort of like a latency. Solid states access times are about what you mentioned and RAM is slightly less than your estimate at about 10-15 nanoseconds from the time the request is made until the data is retrieved.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAS_latency  < RAM info

Comment: "For a completely unknown memory access (AKA Random access), the relevant latency is the time to close any open row, plus the time to open the desired row, followed by the CAS latency to read data from it."

You haven't taken into account the row opening/closing times in that 10-15 ns estimate.